# Reactjs Add spinner when click button

Tags: reactjs

Here is my code:

```
<ButtonOrder
  style={{ background: values.sideNB ? NBColor : NSColor }}
  type="button"
  disabled={isPlacingOrder}
  onClick={handleSubmit}
>
  {isPlacingOrder ? "Đang đặt lệnh" : "Đặt lệnh"}
</ButtonOrder>;
```

How to change to add spinner instead of text when you click on any button with type "button"

Comment: Do you mean hiding the button and showing just a spinner in place of the button?

Comment: I mean view spinner on button instead of text

Comment: Using icons such as FontAwesome popped into my mind. It has several spinning icons too if you can change the text on click.

Comment: do you mean using spinner instead of **Đang đặt lệnh**??

Answer (score 2):

If you just wanna use spinner instead of text (**Đang đặt lệnh**), here a way to do.

```js
const ButtonOrder = ({ children, ...rest }) => {
  return <button {...rest}>{children}</button>;
};

const Spinner = () => (
  <img src="https://loading.io/spinners/microsoft/index.svg" class="zoom2" height="20"/>
)

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    isPlacingOrder: false
  };

  handleSubmit = () => {
    this.setState(
      {
        isPlacingOrder: true
      },
      () => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          this.setState({
            isPlacingOrder: false
          });
        }, 2000);
      }
    );
  }

  render() {
    const { handleSubmit, state } = this;
    const { isPlacingOrder } = state;

    return (
      <ButtonOrder type="button" disabled={isPlacingOrder} onClick={handleSubmit}>
        {isPlacingOrder ? <Spinner /> : "Đặt lệnh"}
      </ButtonOrder>
    );
  }
}


ReactDOM.render(<App />,document.getElementById("app"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check out this implementation for your issues. If you are using redux or any API call while the loader should be visible (toggle), then that would be simple, but for your current case you can follow this:
https://reactjsexample.com/the-easiest-way-to-manage-loaders-errors-inside-a-button/

If you are using material or semantic, then you can check their docs with "spinners" you'll get there.

Answer (score 0):

```
this.state = {
  disabled: false,
  processing: false
}


<TouchableWhatever disabled={this.state.disabled} onPress={this.click.bind(this)}>
  { this.state.processing 
      ? <ActivityIndicator />
      : <Text>Click me</Text>
  }
</TouchableWhatever>


click() {
  this.setState({
    disabled: true, 
    processing: true
  });
  // login, respond
}
```